# Could not able to merge two data frame sets on object column type

Tags: python, pandas, merge

```
merged_df = file1.merge(file1, file2, on="WineType")
```

> ValueError: unknown type str160

`file2.info()`

```
<class ‘pandas.core.frame.DataFrame’>
RangeIndex: 4898 entries, 0 to 4897
Data columns (total 13 columns):

Column Non-Null Count Dtype
0 fixed acidity 4898 non-null float64
1 volatile acidity 4898 non-null float64
2 citric acid 4898 non-null float64
3 residual sugar 4898 non-null float64
4 chlorides 4898 non-null float64
5 free sulfur dioxide 4898 non-null float64
6 total sulfur dioxide 4898 non-null float64
7 density 4898 non-null float64
8 pH 4898 non-null float64
9 sulphates 4898 non-null float64
10 alcohol 4898 non-null float64
11 quality 4898 non-null int64
12 WineType 4898 non-null object
dtypes: float64(11), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 497.6+ KB
```

`file1.info()`

```
<class ‘pandas.core.frame.DataFrame’>
RangeIndex: 1599 entries, 0 to 1598
Data columns (total 13 columns):

Column Non-Null Count Dtype
0 fixed acidity 1599 non-null float64
1 volatile acidity 1599 non-null float64
2 citric acid 1599 non-null float64
3 residual sugar 1599 non-null float64
4 chlorides 1599 non-null float64
5 free sulfur dioxide 1599 non-null float64
6 total sulfur dioxide 1599 non-null float64
7 density 1599 non-null float64
8 pH 1599 non-null float64
9 sulphates 1599 non-null float64
10 alcohol 1599 non-null float64
11 quality 1599 non-null int64
12 WineType 1599 non-null object
dtypes: float64(11), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 162.5+ KB
```

Can you please guide me, how to merge both dataframe in a single file with the common column.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to merge on an `object` data type. `pandas` has no clue how to properly match values from these field. You can try converting to string in both cases, e.g.

```
file1['WineType'] = file1['WineType'].astype(str) 
file2['WineType'] = file2['WineType'].astype(str)
merged_df = file1.merge(file1, file2, on="WineType")
```

And then the merge should be successful.

You can also try `.astype('category')`. More on the column type conversions:
[Change column type from string to float in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-column-type-from-string-to-float-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

i have tried this method also.
`concat_df = pd.concat([file1, file2]).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)` and worked fine.
I have tried the below one also and its working fine.

```
file1['WineType'] = file1['WineType'].astype(str) 
file2['WineType'] = file2['WineType'].astype(str)
merged_df = file1.merge(file1, file2, on="WineType")
```